# Re-executing the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have functions for printing text by step printing text. And the event that happens when you click on the button (that's when the function is triggered). BUT if you press the button several times, the text will be printed on top of another one. If anyone has any ideas what to do with this, I really ask for help. And, if possible, give advice on the code.

```
function printText(element) {
    element.text('')
    const text = element.attr('data-text')
    let counter = 0
    let newText = ''
    const print = setInterval(() => {
      if(counter <= text.length && text[counter] != undefined){
        newText = newText + text[counter]
        counter++
      }else{clearInterval(print)}
      
      element.text(newText)
    }, 30)
  }

  accordingButtons.click(function(e){
    const $target = $(this)
    const $targetBody = $target.attr('class') === 'polygon-but' ? $target.parent().parent().next() : $target.parent().next()

    if($target.attr('data-toggle') == 'true'){
      $targetBody.animate({
        opacity: 0.0,
        height: `0px`,
        marginTop : '0px'
      }, 200)
      $target.attr('data-toggle', 'false')
    }
    else if($target.attr('data-toggle') == 'false'){
      $targetBody.animate({
        opacity: 1,
        height: `+=${$targetBody.attr('data-number')}`,
        marginTop : '37px'
      }, 200)
      $target.attr('data-toggle', 'true')
      printText($targetBody)
    }
    
  })
```

Comment: use clearInterval to clear the interval before you make a new interval

Comment: Or disable your button, as long as one "step" of this is still running, so that the user _can't_ click it too soon.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the intervalID outside the function and add a clearInterval before the setInterval

```js
let print;
function printText(element) {
  element.text('')
  const text = element.attr('data-text')
  let counter = 0
  let newText = ''
  clearInterval(print)  
  print = setInterval(() => {
    if (counter <= text.length && text[counter] != undefined) {
      newText = newText + text[counter]
      counter++
    } else {
      clearInterval(print)
    }
    element.text(newText)
  }, 100)
}
printText($("[data-text"));
// simulate a second click
setTimeout(() => printText($("[data-text")),1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-text="Never gonna give you up"></div>
```